# How does this JSONP Javascript is changed in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert a JSONP pure Javascript code into jQuery.

1. How does the below code change for jQuery?
2. Do I have to use the entire jQuery library or can I use some modules only?

   ```
   function requestServerCall(url) {
       var head = document.head;
       var script = document.createElement("script");
       script.setAttribute("src", url);
       head.appendChild(script);
       head.removeChild(script);
   }


   function Response(data) {
       alert(data.token);
   }

   function group() {
       requestServerCall("http://domain.com?callback=Response&y=" + y + "");
   }

   group();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are lots of options, but:

```
$.ajax("http://domain.com?y=" + y, {
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.token);
    }
});
```

Since jQuery is open source, it's theoretically possible to include only a subset, but the library is not modularized. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this answer but how do I put it into functions for example ?